# Craft internal error exposing sensitive data

Tags: config, error-message, error, error-handling

I have a craft installation and recently my server had issues and on the page rendering mysql and other errors were shown. 
Of course this creates security implications. Is there a way to restrict these errors? My guess it that i just need to change the `devMode` to `false` in `general.php`. Is there anything else i need to do? I am asking because I cannot really reproduce the error anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Your guess is correct... as the docs say, you should never have [devMode](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) enabled in production environments specifically for reasons like this (as well as many others).

If you find errors that are leaking sensitive server info with `devMode` disabled, then that is a bug and should be reported to support@buildwithcraft.com.